# How to troubleshoot this memory usage?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, security, php, java

I have a classifieds website.

I use PHP, MySql, and SOLR.

Solr uses a Servlet Container, in my case JETTY, which is java application.

I just noticed that something was terribly wrong on my website. I opened the terminal and entered the "top" command and noticed that JAVA was EATING all the cpu and mem.

Now I thought "Ok, maybe I need more mem and cpu" So I increased it. But along with the increase the java app started eating more.

This has never happened before, and it is either a bug, or a hack of some kind.

Anyways, I need to troubleshoot this now, and so I wonder how do I do this?

Can I somehow pinpoint exactly when the memory usage started to go up from some error log?

How does one troubleshoot this?

How do I prevent it? Is it possible to prevent too many requests somehow, if they are within a timeline?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How much RAM are you using? SOLR has a known issue dealing with [FieldCache](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/search/FieldCache.html) which can cause it to eat huge amounts of memory while doing sorted searches.

Edit:

Okay, try using *pmap -d* on your big three processes (httpd/php, MySQL, Jetty) and see if some sub-library is eating up all your memory.

Comment: I have 4GB of ram at my disposal. Java is only using 2% of this.

Answer (score 1):

Your java process is always goind to eat as much as the -Xmx value.
When it reaches this value, it starts to recycle its memory.

If you want lower memory usage and if your application works fine with it, you just need to tune down your JVM Xmx parameter.

I've once got a memory leak in a C library called by one java program, that kept the process memory usage growing, while the Java heap was stable. But that's very unlikely.

There are plenty of [tools](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/monitoring/) to watch your java heap, but you should start by logging a few java.lang.Runtime.totalMemory ...

Answer (score -1):

I believe that there might be some virus or spy attack on your server. Scan your server with some of best antivirus and spyware softwares.